# Xamarin: How to CarouselView disable sliding page

Tags: xamarin, view, touch, carousel

Hello I have drawable view inside CarouselView. I having problem drawing something with touch event on the drawable view and I am not able to prevent CarouselView from sliding left or right. Is it possible to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment there is not much documentation about this control but if you look at the purpose of the CarouselView, I would say no to your question. Sliding left and right and showing items in its source is the purpose of CarouselView.